# client side current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I have a Rails/Backbone app that implements Devise authentication with JavaScript/Ajax (using backbone). After the user logs in, I assign the userSession response object from devise to the app.currentUser to create a client side currentUser.

```
app.currentUser = userSession;
```

However, the way I'm using currentUser, I might as well just give it a boolean value because I don't use any of that userSession information.

Moving on, inside other methods of my app, I check for authorization by seeing if there is a current user like this

```
if(!app.currentUser) {
        this.trigger("pleaseSignIn");
        return; 
    }
    else { 
     ....
```

This works fine when I test it--If the user's not logged he can't continue to certain parts of the app.  However, anyone with basic javascript skills would be able to bypass the login by setting `app.currentUser = true` in the console.   I'm not protecting state secrets behind my authorization; it's just intended to encouraging signup etc. 
My question is, is there a way to beef this up a little bit without checking if the current user exists on the server side (i.e. devise sets a current user server sideon login).

One (weak) strategy I considered was using totally meaningless names for my variables. I.e. instead of `if(!app.currentUser) {` I might say `if(!app.godNotDead)` so that someone would at least have to get past nonsense to hack my porous authentication wall. However, I'm still hoping for something a little more robust.

Maybe I should explain a little more how the app works. It does not have an authentication wall at the beginning. Rather, users can play with certain parts of the app, it's only when they try to click on other portions of the app that they're asked to login.

FYI, in the normal devise set up, authorization is checked in the Rails controllers on the server and can't be bypassed this way.

Answer (score 0):

the best way would be get the state from rails and not client-side

```
UserModel.fetch()
// returns a user model if there is one, if not then you are obviously not authenticated
```

or, i think better, use a token as a param on your requests to the server

```
?token={some hash the server gave you}
```

so that its not just a boolean, you need a token